# Duda ciclo repetir PSEINT

Tags: pseint

Hola como podria hacer para que este programa pueda detenerse luego de que se muestre el mensaje "ACCESO PERMITIDO?

> Elaborar un programa que simule una clave de acceso. Si el usuario es: "ADMIN" y la clave "123456" mostrar el mensaje "ACCESO PERMITIDO" caso contrario mostrar el mensaje "ACCESO DENEGADO".

```
    Algoritmo actividad6
Repetir
        
Escribir "Ingrese el nombre de usuario" 
leer usuario 
Escribir "Ingrese su contraseña" 
leer contraseña

Si usuario != ADMIN y contraseña <> 123456 Entonces
    Escribir  "ACCESO DENEGADO"
SiNo
    Escribir  "ACCESO PERMITIDO"
Fin Si
Hasta Que usuario = ADMIN y contraseña == 123456 
FinAlgoritmo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usuario = ADMIN no son dos ==?

Comment: perdon me olvide de agregar el == a usuario , me sigue funcionando igual el programa

Answer (score 1):

```
Algoritmo actividad6
    Definir usuario Como Caracter
    Definir contraseña Como Caracter
    
    Mientras usuario <> "ADMIN" y contraseña <> "123456" Hacer
        Escribir "Ingrese el nombre de usuario" 
        leer usuario 
        Escribir "Ingrese su contraseña" 
        leer contraseña
    Fin Mientras
    
    Escribir  "ACCESO PERMITIDO"
FinAlgoritmo
```

Con este codigo lo podras resolver, cuando quieres comparar texto/strings hay que ponerlo entre comillas, sino el programa lo puede confundir con una variable que no existe.

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema es que la validación está hecha al revés. Por ejemplo, si la contraseña es correcta y el usuario es incorrecto, te va a decir igual ACCESO PERMITIDO (porque no cae específicamente en el caso en el que ambos estén mal). Invierte la validación

Lo otro: estás comparando con algo que no es un número `ADMIN` pero que tampoco estás tratando como una cadena. No sé bien cómo funciona PSEINT pero suena a que lo tratas como una variable. En general, busca tratar ambos datos como cadenas, con comillas dobles.

Esos dos cambios dan el resultado que buscas.

```
Algoritmo actividad6
    Repetir
        
        Escribir "Ingrese el nombre de usuario" 
        leer usuario 
        Escribir "Ingrese su contraseña" 
        leer contraseña
        
        Si usuario == "ADMIN" Y contraseña == "123456" Entonces
            Escribir  "ACCESO PERMITIDO"
        SiNo
            Escribir  "ACCESO DENEGADO"
        Fin Si
    Hasta Que usuario == "ADMIN" Y contraseña == "123456" 
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Algoritmo actividad6
Definir usuario Como Caracter
Definir contraseña Como Caracter

```
Mientras usuario <> "ADMIN" y contraseña <> "123456" Hacer
    Escribir "Ingrese el nombre de usuario" 
    leer usuario 
    Escribir "Ingrese su contraseña" 
    leer contraseña
Fin Mientras

Escribir  "ACCESO PERMITIDO"
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: Además de que tu respuesta no describe lo qué hace y tiene un formato incorrecto, ¿en qué se diferencia de [esta otra](/a/463853)?